Movie about a desk and letters from the past
Looking for a movie I watched a long time ago about a desk with a hidden compartment. When the new owner of the desk finds the hidden compartment and looks inside, he finds a letter that dates a few hundred years back. He decides to write a response and somehow that letter is being transported into the past to a girl who reads the letter in her own time period. They start corresponding with one another.

When was "a long time ago"?

Sounds like  The Love Letter from 1998 with Campbell Scott and Jennifer Jason Leigh:

Scotty Corrigan buys an antique desk and finds a Civil War-era letter inside it, written by a woman who died over a hundred years ago. Fancifully, he writes and mails a reply...only to have it reach its destination in the past. As Elizabeth and Scotty continue their remarkable correspondence, they find themselves falling in love, and more than restless about their impending, respective, marriages. 

Here's a video with some clips from the film:




That's exactly the one I was looking for! Thanks

Romantic time travelling letters also feature in The Lake House (2006)
